# Why does list1.remove(0) give the first element in the list?

Tags: java, list

In a java course homework I was asked to describe what the following code does:

```
while (!list1.isEmpty()) {
list2.add(list2.size(), list1.remove(0));
}
```

At first I thought this is actually removing the first element of list1, then add the remaining right behind list2.

But after I run a simulation program as following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testQ1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    System.out.println(list1);
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8));
    System.out.println(list2);

    while (!list1.isEmpty())
    {
      list2.add(list2.size(), list1.remove(0));
    }
    System.out.println(list2);
   }
}
```

It gives me the result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So I try to print "list1.remove(0)" before the while loop to see what it is. Then the result becomes:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
1
[5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now it prints "1" as what "list1.remove(0)" is. And merge the remaining list1 into list2 just as I thought before.
From What I know, remove(int index) method is used to removes the element at the specified position in this list.

My question then is: What exactly does list.remove(int index) give as a result?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? It tells you *exactly*...

Comment: *Returns:
the element that was removed from the list*

Comment: Sorry that I don't know this but what documentation are you referring to? Thx

Comment: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)]  _Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list._

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thx a lot！

Comment: @Ian My bad not reading them carefully, the answer is just down there in the details..... thank you!

Comment: Better link for javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/.  Java 7 is at end-of-life.  We're almost up to Java 9, which is scheduled for release in September.  The `remove` doc won't be any different, but it's best to use the most up-to-date version in general.

Comment: Since `remove()` changes the list, if you want to see what it removes, you'll need a temporary variable: `int temp = list1.remove(0); System.out.println(temp); list2.add(list2.size(),temp);`

Comment: @EricChen Bookmark the base URL for those docs. I'm an expert JVM developer and refer to them frequently.

Answer (score 5):

`List::remove` returns the element that was removed. You removed a `1`, so that's what was returned.

[Always check the docs first for questions like this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-). The documentation of the method explains what the return value represents. With a library as mature as Java's, the docs will explain 99% of your questions.

Just remove the element, *then* return the list.

Comment: It is returning `1` because the is the value of the object being removed from the list

Comment: I fixed my answer after looking at the docs. My bad. I was thinking it was "symmetrical with respect to `add`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, but it answers the question. If a question can be answered in as little content as a comment, should it not be an answer?

Comment: @ajb Sorry, grabbed the first Google link without verifying version :/ Give me a sec.

Comment: @ajb Updated to the Java 8 version.

Comment: *No, but it answers the question.* - it does now eh ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm drunk and tired. Give me a break. Trying to help out :0